# Running monerod in the cloud on SSD volume, but with a tight limit on IOPS imposed by the provider. Will the PR #1506 help?

Tags: monerod, synchronization, database

I'm running monerod on an Amazon EC2 instance with an SSD volume (`gp2` volume type), and synchronization from scratch gets extremely slow after I've used up my burst credits (allowing me up to 3000 IOPS for a limited time instead of 100). See also my question [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3159/started-monerod-0-10-1-on-an-aws-ec2-t2-micro-instance-why-does-it-sync-so-slow) for details.

My follow up question now is if [PR #1506](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/1506) will significantly decrease disk IOPS as a side effect of addressing [issue #1463](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/1463). The description says that the number of DB txn is reduced to 1 for each batch, and I'm assuming but am not entirely sure that this also means much fewer IOPS on the disk side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, judging from my test results PR#1506 should reduce the IOPS requirement by at least half.